# Mac port errors on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: macports, osx-mountain-lion

I upgraded to Mountain lion and now ports aren't being installed. I've updated macports using the dmg, downloaded the command line tools via Xcode and I even tried installing the commandline tools by downloading it from the apple developer site. The error seems to be a syntax error somewhere (though I'm getting the same syntax error for ANY port I'm trying to install so it doesn't seem to be specific to any port).

```
:info:configure configure: creating ./config.status
:info:configure config.status: creating install-info/tests/defs
:info:configure nawk: syntax error at source line 1 source file ./confPOrdDb/subs.awk
:info:configure  context is
:info:configure      >>> BEGIN <<<  {
:info:configure nawk: bailing out at source line 321
:info:configure config.status: error: could not create install-info/tests/defs
:info:configure Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_texinfo/texinfo/work/texinfo-4.13" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local 
:info:configure Exit code: 1
:error:configure org.macports.configure for port texinfo returned: configure failure: command execution failed
:debug:configure Error code: NONE
```

If I run `sudo ./configure --prefix=/opt/local` in the source folder I get the same syntax error.
Any ideas for fixing this?

Comment: Just to be sure. You did do port selfupdate or port sync first to update the ports tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was more than 1 version of nawk installed. I got rid of both and everything went fine